# How to write code to script tag with Flask?

Tags: javascript, html, flask

For example, if the html looks like so :

```html
<body>
{{something}}
</body>
```

with flask you can do

```
def showhomepage():
    var = "hello"
    return render_template("index.html", something = var )
```

What if instead my html looked like this

```html
<body>
</body
<script>
{{something}}
</script>
```

and the function I want inside something is printcars.

```js
function printCars(){
    const cars = ['car1', 'car2'];
    console.log(cars);
}
```

How could I make Flask render the html page such that function `printCars()` is inside the script tag where `{{something}}` is?

Comment: are you asking, how to use your value "something" inside of your JavaScript function?

Comment: Have you tested what happens if you make your JS function a Python string and pass it to  your variable `something`? i.e. in your example replace `'hello'` with your JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the function in a variable.

```py
print_car_func = '''
function printCars(){
    const cars = ['car1', 'car2'];
    console.log(cars);
}
'''

def showhomepage():
    var = print_car_func
    return render_template("index.html", something=var )
```